# Preserved lime is browning and fading inside the brine

Tags: food-preservation, citrus

I read a lot about preserved lemons (TLDR: quarter them, and keep them in a mix of lemon juice and salted/brined water for 10-30 days), and I'm trying it with limes. But...

Two things concern me about my current mixture:

- The lime skin, which was a nice vibrant green, is turning a dark greenish (almost brown) colour
- In some places, the colour leeched off entirely and it's white (like the inside of the rind

Am I doing this right, or is this starting to rot?

I brined them in a combination of salt, water, and lemon juice for about three or four days prior to noticing this. Now (another four days later), they're even more dull-coloured.

(I don't have a picture, sorry. On closer inspection, the dark green/brown looks like it's fading.)

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more? What does your brine consist of and what method are you using exactly? How many days in are the limes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since sliced them open, and they seem to be doing okay.

Answer (score 0):

Its normal for the skin of the lemons to turn brown. I have never made this with anything other than lemons and hawaiian salt. These are left in the sun for a bit, 5 months are so. Often times the jar is turned on its side and rotated every so often. You can Google "Kitchen Craig, Recipes from my kitchen" for a very good recipe and explanation of the process. He also has a photo of his preserved lemons so you can compare.